# How to convert degree/mins to decimal in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I've googled it a lot but did not find any solution. I want to convert Lat Long data (degree, min, sec) to decimal in excel.

Traditionally lat long data is like `25°43'21.3"`, but the database I'm working do not have degree (°) symbol, It has dot(.) instead of degree.For example- `25.43'21.3"`

So What will be a script to convert `25.43'21.3"` into decimal like- `25.722583333333333` ??

the following code works when data comes with (°) symbol.

```
    Function Convert_Decimal(Degree_Deg As String) As Double
   ' Declare the variables to be double precision floating-point.
   Dim degrees As Double
   Dim minutes As Double
   Dim seconds As Double
   ' Set degree to value before "°" of Argument Passed.
   degrees = Val(Left(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") - 1))
   ' Set minutes to the value between the "°" and the "'"
   ' of the text string for the variable Degree_Deg divided by
   ' 60. The Val function converts the text string to a number.
   minutes = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "°") + 2, _
             InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, _
             "°") - 2)) / 60
    ' Set seconds to the number to the right of "'" that is
    ' converted to a value and then divided by 3600.
    seconds = Val(Mid(Degree_Deg, InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") + _
            2, Len(Degree_Deg) - InStr(1, Degree_Deg, "'") - 2)) _
            / 3600
   Convert_Decimal = degrees + minutes + seconds
End Function
```

Comment: just replace `"°"` with `"."`

Comment: how would replacing work? data contains several dot(.)

Comment: `InStr` will return the position of the first `.` it finds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Private Const vbQuote As String = """"

Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print answer("25.43'21.3""")
End Sub


Public Function answer(ByVal s As String) As Double
    Dim degrees As Double
    Dim minutes As Double
    Dim seconds As Double

    Dim dotPos As Integer 'position of first dot in the string
    Dim commaPos As Integer 'position of comma in the string
    Dim quotePos As Integer 'position of quote in the string

    dotPos = InStr(s, ".")
    commaPos = InStr(s, "'")
    quotePos = InStr(s, vbQuote)

    If dotPos = 0 Or _
        commaPos = 0 Or _
        quotePos = 0 Or _
        dotPos > commaPos Or _
        commaPos > quotePos Then

        'some error handling here
        Stop
    End If

    degrees = CDbl(Left(s, dotPos - 1))
    minutes = CDbl(Mid(s, dotPos + 1, commaPos - dotPos - 1))
    seconds = CDbl(Mid(s, commaPos + 1, quotePos - commaPos - 1))

    answer = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But the script returns 0.722583333 orginal value will be 25.722583333, what is wrong with it? I've keep 25.43'21.3" on A1 and type: =answer(A1) on B1 cell. what I've missed?

Comment: Oops. I had misspelt 'degrees' in a few places. All fixed now ;-)